# Launch easycraft

Tags: software-installation

I installed EasyCraft from the terminal.  After the install I rebooted.  I am unable to find where it installed, or how to launch the game.  I doubled checked, and the program is installed correctly.

Comment: Why the reboot?

Comment: Did we solve it?

Answer (score 2):

> After the install I rebooted

Not needed on Ubuntu by the way.

> I installed EasyCraft from the terminal

So run the program from terminal? If you used the command `sudo apt-get install easycraft` then you want the name of it, like

```
easycraft
```

or if you installed with `sudo apt-get install easycraft-game` then you run with `easycraft-game` (normally).

Have you searched the dash for `easycraft`?